# Java Load image from URLConnection

Tags: java, url, image, arrays, urlconnection

I have a URLConnection, that access a web page.

```
URL url = new URL("https://domain");
   con = url.openConnection();
   con.setDoOutput(true);
```

Then i sent some data to the server using `con.setRequestProperty()`

I get the response cookies fro ma specified field using

```
String headerValue = con.getHeaderField(6);
```

I also get the html and parse an image url from there. But here is a problem. I can get this image only by sending cache data back to the server ,when i acces my image.

So i open a new connection

```
URL url1 = new URL("https://domain/image); 
    URLConnection con1 = url1.openConnection();
```

I send the cookies back to the server `con1.setRequestProperty("Cookie", headerValue);`

And finally i try to acces the image using BufferedInputStream and then creating an iamge in a JLabel

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con1.getInputStream());
       ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       int c;
       while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
         byteArrayOut.write(c);
       }


       Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
               byteArrayOut.toByteArray());

    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

The problem is this seems to not work. Is it another way to get an file from a server through a URlConnection?
Error code

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://domain/image
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Status code 400 means "Bad Request", so the client send something that was invalid or that the server did not understand. Can you add the value of the Cookie header that you set in your request?

Comment: oh, i were thinking of this but only after your comment i tryed to modify the cookis request. actually server sent me cookies like "4ASP.NET_SessionId=5gw3fg55ildrqs552q5qoa55; path=/; HttpOnly" and it want me to sent back only 4ASP.NET_SessionId=5gw3fg55ildrqs552q5qoa55; , without other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Case closed. 
Used this code to split the cookies string.

```
String temp = headerValue.substring(0, (len1-17));
```

Comment: You can also accept your own answer to a question. If you do so, please show a bit of code for your solution, i.e. how you modify the cookie value before sending it back.